# how to loop with multiple index in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have to write a loop which is very simple in languages like java and c.

```
for (int i = 0; i <arr.length()-1; i++) {
   for (int j = i+1; j <arr.length(); j++) {
      //process
   }
}
```

But I can't get to mimic this in Python. For example:

```
for number in arr:
    print(number)
```

But how to iterate with the i and j indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
ll = len(arr)

for i in range(ll):
    for j in range(i+1, ll, 1):
        # process
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested loop, the same as you would in another language:

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    for j in range(i, len(arr))::
        print(arr[j])
```

or:

```
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    for number in arr[i:]:
        print(number)
```

or perhaps:

```
for i, n1 in enumerate(arr[:-1]):
    for j, n2 in enumerate(arr[i:], i):
        print(f"arr[{i}] = {n1}, arr[{j}] = {n2}")
```

depending on whether your processing needs to operate on the elements themselves, the indices, and/or both.